# Show that $Av=Aw=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\omega$ be a complex number such that $\omega^3=1$, but $\omega\neq1$. If   $$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&\omega&\omega^2\\ \omega&\omega^2&1 \\ \omega^2&\omega&1\end{pmatrix}\quad $$ then show that there exist linearly independent vectors $v, w \in \mathbb C^3$ such that $Av=Aw=0.$ I tried to show $0$ is an at least $2$-fold eigenvalue of $A$ but couldn't.

Comment: I think you mean to say $v,w \in \mathbb{C}^3.$

Comment: Sorry ... corrected my question.

Comment: I attempted it and it seems like the eigenspace for eigenvalue 0 is only of dimension 1...

Comment: Did you mean the last row to be $(\omega^2, 1, \omega)$ instead?

Comment: @copper.hat: Nope. That would make it trivial.

Comment: It would make it possible. As the question stands, it is impossible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible. It is easy to see that $A (1,1,1)^T = 0$, hence $\dim \ker A \geq 1$. However, the vectors $(1, \omega, \omega^2)^T$ and $(\omega, \omega^2, \omega)^T$ are linearly independent, hence $\dim {\cal R} (A) \geq  2$. It follows from the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim \ker A = 1$.